# Images according to attributes magento

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, product-images

I was trying to create a section in backend product edit page of Magento.
Under Images section, I was willing to add images for variations directly from there. I have tried searching for something useful but couldn't find something. I wasn't able to find anything useful yet.

Is there any way we could alter images part?

Also, I wasn't able to create some code for that so don't ask for any code I have tried.

Comment: so you want to add variations image in parent (configurable) product ?

Comment: Yes the images part , I need to add variation images directly from there.

Comment: Clarify - when making configurable product with 'size' and 'color' - in the configurable creation, you want to add your image for 'size' or 'color' while creating a configurable product in the configurable product image section - not in the "create configuration" panel. 

I think it's a good idea. If I have 4 colors and 10 sizes, magento creates 40 images, when 4 would work for me. And if I add a 5th item later with a new color and 10 sizes, magento will want to create a complete matrix spanning all possible combinations of size/color - I hope this becomes a module.

Comment: I just need a way so that attribute images can be directly added from Images tab.